# argparse: How to map choices to different values?

Tags: python, argparse

When using argparse, I would like a user to select from `choices`, but I would like their choice to determine a more complex value (similar to how `store_const` works).

For example, when choosing from a `smoker` status of `['current', 'former', 'never']`, I would like `current` to map to `'Current every day smoker.'`

Is there an elegant way to do this?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--smoker', choices=['current','former','never'])
print(vars(parser.parse_args()))
```

Normal output:

```
$ ./script.py --smoker current
{'smoker': 'current'}
```

Desired:

```
$ ./script.py --smoker current
{'smoker': 'Current every day smoker.'}
```

I thought I could do this with a `lambda` type argument, but `argparse` enforces the list of choices:

```
choice_dict = {'current': 'Current everyday...'}
parser.add_argument('--smoker', type=lambda x: choice_dict[x], choices=choice_dict.keys())
print(vars(parser.parse_args()))

./script.py --smoker current
usage: script.py [-h] [--smoker {current}]
script.py: error: argument --smoker: invalid choice: 'Current everyday...' (choose from 'current')
```

Comment: IMO that should not be the responsibility of your argument parser, but some other component that formats your desired output.

Comment: The string is first passed through the `type`, and then the `choices` are checked.  You can give the `keys` as choices, but don't use the `type`.  After parsing use `choice_dict[args.smoker]` to convert the key to value.

Comment: You could do the conversion in the `type`, without `choices`.  But you won't get the `help`, and you may need to tweak the error class.

Answer (score 3):

Though I agree with 0x5452 comment that it is better to decouple this formatting from the parser, you can use an `Action` to do what you want:

```py
import argparse

CONVERSION_TABLE = {'current': 'Currently smokes',
                    'former': 'Used to smoke',
                    'never': 'Never smoke'}

class RenameOption(argparse.Action):
     def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
         setattr(namespace, self.dest, CONVERSION_TABLE[values])

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--smoker', action=RenameOption, choices=CONVERSION_TABLE)
print(vars(parser.parse_args()))
```

The result is:

```bash
$ python test.py --smoker current
{'smoker': 'Currently smokes'}

$ python test.py --smoker no
usage: test.py [-h] [--smoker {current,former,never}]
test.py: error: argument --smoker: invalid choice: 'no' (choose from 'current', 'former', 'never')
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a clever use of `action=`

I ended up using a `lambda` with a `metavar` definition:

`parser.add_argument('--smoker', type=lambda x: CONVERSION_TABLE[x], metavar=list(CONVERSION_TABLE.keys())`